# preg match all in array searching for [ ]

Tags: php, arrays, regex, preg-match-all, modbus

i have found the solution mysqlf using:

```
foreach ($output as $value) {
    if (strpos($value, "]:") > -1) {
        $tal = substr($value, strpos($value, "]:") +3) . "<br>";
        echo $tal;
    }
}
```

this returns:
-210
-212

---

Thanks in advance.

I want to preg so i only get the line: [10] => [147]: -210
or both [10] => [147]: -210 and [21] => [148]: -212

how can i preg `[147]:` or is there a better way to get the specific information?

my array $output contains:

```
Array
(
    [0] => modpoll 3.4 - FieldTalk(tm) Modbus(R) Master Simulator
    [1] => Copyright (c) 2002-2013 proconX Pty Ltd
    [2] => Visit http://www.modbusdriver.com for Modbus libraries and tools.
    [3] => 
    [4] => Protocol configuration: MODBUS/TCP
    [5] => Slave configuration...: address = 1, start reference = 147, count = 1
    [6] => Communication.........: 10.234.6.11, port 502, t/o 1.00 s, poll rate 1000 ms
    [7] => Data type.............: 16-bit register, output (holding) register table
    [8] => 
    [9] => -- Polling slave...
    [10] => [147]: -210
    [11] => modpoll 3.4 - FieldTalk(tm) Modbus(R) Master Simulator
    [12] => Copyright (c) 2002-2013 proconX Pty Ltd
    [13] => Visit http://www.modbusdriver.com for Modbus libraries and tools.
    [14] => 
    [15] => Protocol configuration: MODBUS/TCP
    [16] => Slave configuration...: address = 1, start reference = 148, count = 1
    [17] => Communication.........: 10.234.6.11, port 502, t/o 1.00 s, poll rate 1000 ms
    [18] => Data type.............: 16-bit register, output (holding) register table
    [19] => 
    [20] => -- Polling slave...
    [21] => [148]: -212
)

$matches  = preg_grep ('/^[147] (\w+)/i', $output);
print_r ($matches);
//only returns Array()
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape the opening square bracket because `[147]` is seen as a character class that contains `1`, `4` and `7`

You can do this with:

```
$result=preg_grep('~^\[14(?:7|8)]:~',$rgData);
print_r($result);
```

You can find all that you want to know about escaping (or not) square brackets [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17845014/what-does-the-regex-mean/17845034#17845034)