# regular expression for finding string between [[ ]] and {{}}

Tags: java, regex

How could I find string between `[[` `]]`? After searching a answer I find this method below, but I cannot find the regular expression for `[[` `]]`, neither for `{{` `}}`.

What I want to do is to find e.g. `[[abc]]XXXXXXXXXX[[def]]`, and save `abc`, `def` as a ArrayList.

```
String s = "[[abc]]XXXXXXXXXX[[def]]";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[[(.*?)]]")
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
if (m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group(i)); // => "abc","def"
}
```

Comment: Could they contain nested and/or escaped brackets/braces?

Comment: You'll need to escape the `[` since they're regex special characters.

Comment: @Amber or use `[[][[](.*?)[]][]]` :P

Comment: @HamZa yay for readability :D

Comment: What should be result for this kind of data `{{a[[b]]e}}`, `[[a{{b}}c]]`? Or maybe this kind of input is impossible?

Comment: {{a[[b]]e}}, [[a{{b}}c]] is impossible. If [[]] is not easy to express in regex, how about {{}}? any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You must double escape the opening square brackets (you can do the same with the closing) since they are used to define character classes:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\[\\[(.*?)]]");
```

(exactly the same with curly braces, that are used for quantifiers)

You can read this [fabulous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17845014/what-does-the-regex-mean/17845034#17845034) about the incredible world of square brackets.