# Python re.match only characters, digits and some punctuations

Tags: python, regex

I am using this re.match call to get only "proper" strings:

```
re.match('^[A-Za-z0-9\.\,\:\;\!\?\(\)]', str)
```

But I am getting some garbage too, like `#` and `_`. How is that possible? What am I doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show sample input, and output?

Comment: `print re.match('^[A-Za-z0-9\.\,\:\;\!\?\(\)]', "#")` returns `None`, as expected. Please clarify the question with some examples.

Comment: You don't need the start-of-line `^` anchor with `match()` because it only finds matches at the beginning of the string.

Comment: Usually you don't have to escape special characters other than `[]` inside a character-class.

Comment: You don't have to escape anything (except `^`) inside character sets, just FYI.

Comment: None of those characters are metacharacters inside the brackets - they need not be escaped.  Some of them, (`,` and `;`) aren't metacharacters at in regex at all.  Unnecessary escapes turn your regex into unreadable character soup - I would recommend not using them.

Comment: Actually, Vince and henry, you're both kind of right, and kind of wrong - inside a character set you only **need** to escape the closing bracket `]`, but the characters `^` and `-` both have special meanings relative to their position in the set, and so may need to be escaped (or moved).

Comment: @FrankieTheKneeMan: The `]` can be moved at the first position, then you don't need to escape it. Take a look at this incredible post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17845014/what-does-the-regex-mean/17845034#17845034

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Awesome.

Answer (score 4):

Use this to check all characters until the end of your string, otherwhise your pattern will only check the first character:

```
re.match('^[A-Za-z0-9.,:;!?()]+$', str)
```

Note that the character class doesn't contain spaces, newlines or tabs. You can add them like this:

```
re.match('^[A-Za-z0-9.,:;!?()\s]+$', str)
```

If you want to allow void strings you can replace the `+` quantifier by `*`

Comment: How come you don't use `\d` for `0-9`.  Any special reason or is it just preference?

Comment: @iCodez: `\d` and `0-9` are not always the same since the meaning of `\d` can be "all digits in any language". `[0-9]` is not ambiguous