# How to find all possible regex matches in python?

Tags: python, regex, parentheses

I am trying to find all possible word/tag pairs or other nested combinations with python and its regular expressions.

```
sent = '(NP (NNP Hoi) (NN Hallo) (NN Hey) (NNP (NN Ciao) (NN Adios)))'

def checkBinary(sentence):
    n = re.findall("\([A-Za-z-0-9\s\)\(]*\)", sentence)
    print(n)

checkBinary(sent)

Output:
['(NP (NNP Hoi) (NN Hallo) (NN Hey) (NNP (NN Ciao) (NN Adios)))']
```

looking for:

```
['(NP (NNP Hoi) (NN Hallo) (NN Hey) (NNP (NN Ciao) (NN Adios)))', 
 '(NNP Hoi)', 
 '(NN Hallo)',
 '(NN Hey)', 
 '(NNP (NN Ciao) (NN Adios))',
 '(NN Ciao)',
 '(NN Adios)']
```

I think the regex formula could find the nested parenthesis word/tag pairs aswell but it doesn't return them. How should I do this?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

it's actually not possible to do this by using regular expressions, because regular expressions express a language defined by a ***regular*** grammar that can be solved by a non finite deterministic automaton, where matching is represented by states ; then to match nested parenthesis, you'd need to be able to match an infinite number of parenthesis and then have an automaton with an infinite number of states.

To be able to cope with that, we use what's called a push-down automaton, that is used to define the ***context free*** grammar.

[image: Chomsky's hierarchy]

So if your regex does not match nested parenthesis, it's because it's expressing the following automaton and does not match anything on your input:

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Play with it](https://www.debuggex.com/r/6l3LbGcFZh59HIJn)

As a reference, please have a look at MIT's courses on the topic:

- http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-045j-automata-computability-and-complexity-spring-2011/lecture-notes/MIT6_045JS11_lec04.pdf
- http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-005-elements-of-software-construction-fall-2011/lecture-notes/MIT6_005F11_lec05.pdf
- http://www.saylor.org/site/wp-content/uploads/2012/01/CS304-2.1-MIT.pdf

So one of the ways to parse your string efficiently, is to build a grammar for nested parenthesis (`pip install pyparsing` first):

```
>>> import pyparsing
>>> strings = pyparsing.Word(pyparsing.alphanums)
>>> parens  = pyparsing.nestedExpr( '(', ')', content=strings)
>>> parens.parseString('(NP (NNP Hoi) (NN Hallo) (NN Hey) (NNP (NN Ciao) (NN Adios)))').asList()
[['NP', ['NNP', 'Hoi'], ['NN', 'Hallo'], ['NN', 'Hey'], ['NNP', ['NN', 'Ciao'], ['NN', 'Adios']]]]
```

N.B.: there exists a few regular expressions engines that do implement nested parenthesis matching using the push down. The default python `re` engine is not one of them, but an alternative engine exists, called [`regex`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/regex) (`pip install regex`) that can do recursive matching (which makes the re engine context free), cf [this code snippet](https://code.google.com/p/mrab-regex-hg/issues/detail?id=78):

```
>>> import regex
>>> res = regex.search(r'(?<rec>\((?:[^()]++|(?&rec))*\))', '(NP (NNP Hoi) (NN Hallo) (NN Hey) (NNP (NN Ciao) (NN Adios)))')
>>> res.captures('rec')
['(NNP Hoi)', '(NN Hallo)', '(NN Hey)', '(NN Ciao)', '(NN Adios)', '(NNP (NN Ciao) (NN Adios))', '(NP (NNP Hoi) (NN Hallo) (NN Hey) (NNP (NN Ciao) (NN Adios)))']
```

Comment: CS at it's essence. +1

Comment: Oh modern regex [could match](http://regex101.com/r/dS9kM8) this kind of data. Read about [recursive patterns](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17845014/what-does-the-regex-mean/17845034#17845034) and/or [balancing groups](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17003799/what-are-regular-expression-balancing-groups/17004406#17004406). [Reference](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22944075)

Comment: indeed, and I even suggest a recursive pattern solution at the end. Though, per definition, those are not ***regular*** expressions anymore.

Comment: Whoa, I stopped reading before reaching the end. I must check this `regex` module. +1

Comment: @zmo Although being right about the concept of regular expressions used in modern languages being similar to regular expression in language theory, you are wrong in assuming they are exactly the same. Regular expressions in modern languages cannot be represented by a regular grammer(some). See my answer.

Comment: @FarhadAliNoo Per definition of [regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#Formal_definition) in formal theory, a regular expression is implementing a regular grammar. The engines implementing non-regular expressions should take a different name, like *nregex* (for *non-regular expressions*) or *cfex* (*context-free expressions*)… Even though those abilities have been implemented in *regex* engines, **calling them *regex* is like calling *a plane* "*a car that can fly*"**. So maybe someone should make an article on HN to complain about that :-)

Comment: @zmo Yes. I agree. The fact that we are still calling those patterns regular expressions and they have not really been regular expressions for years is very misleading.

Comment: let's blame the Perl people! :-D

Comment: Thanks guys, you've been a great help!

Answer (score 2):

Regular expressions used in modern languages DO NOT represent regular languages. zmo is right in saying that regular languages in Language Theroy are represented by finite state automata but the regular expressions that use any sort of backtracking like those with capturing groups, lookarounds and etc that are used in modern languages CANNOT be represented by FSAs known in Language Theory. How can you represent a pattern like (\w+)\1 with a DFA or even and NFA?

The regular expression you are looking for can be something like this(only matches to two levels):

```
(?=(\((?:[^\)\(]*\([^\)]*\)|[^\)\(])*?\)))
```

I tested this on http://regexhero.net/tester/

The matches are in the captured groups:

1: (NP (NNP Hoi) (NN Hallo) (NN Hey) (NNP (NN Ciao) (NN Adios))

1: (NNP Hoi)

1: (NN Hallo)

1: (NN Hey)

1: (NNP (NN Ciao) (NN Adios))

1: (NN Ciao)

1: (NN Adios)

Comment: I believe @zmo talked about modern regular expression in the ending `NB` part (and gave an example using recursion). Also be careful, your expression doesn't go deeper than two level of nesting: your first match is missing the closing parenthesis.

Comment: Oh you are right ! Yes that regex is only good for two levels of nesting.

Comment: I encourage everyone to read about balancing groups and recursive patterns Hamza mentioned in zmo's post's comment section. A very good read indeed.

Comment: Farhad, Thank you aswell for the help! I think ill go with the other answer but thanks for the quick response!