# Regular expression to filter out URLs with a literal dot after the last slash

Tags: python, regex

I need the regex to identify urls that after the last forward slash

- have a literal dot, such as

  ```
  http://www.example.es/cat1/cat2/some-example_DH148439#.Rh1-js_4
  ```
- do not have a literal dot, such as

  ```
  http://www.example.es/cat1/cat2/cat3
  ```

So far I have only found the regular expression for matching everything before `^(.*[\\\/])` or after the last forward slash: `[^/]+$` as well as to match everything after a literal point after the last slash `(?!.*\.)(.*)` Yet I am unable to come out with the above, please help.

Comment: If this is the requested URL, then the fragment identifier (ie. everything after the `#` eg `.Rh1-js_4`) is not actually passed to the server, so you can't check this server-side. (?)

Answer (score 1):

Well, as usual, using a regex to match an URL is the wrong tool for the wrong job. You can use [urlparse](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html) (or [urllib.parse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html) in python3) to do the job, in a very pythonic way:

```
>>> from urlparse import urlparse
>>> urlparse('http://www.example.es/cat1/cat2/some-example_DH148439#.Rh1-js_4')
ParseResult(scheme='http', netloc='www.example.es', path='/cat1/cat2/some-example_DH148439', params='', query='', fragment='.Rh1-js_4')
>>> urlparse('http://www.example.es/cat1/cat2/cat3')
ParseResult(scheme='http', netloc='www.example.es', path='/cat1/cat2/cat3', params='', query='', fragment='')
```

and if you really want a regex, the following regex is an example that would answer your question:

```
import re
>>> re.match(r'^[^:]+://([^.]+\.)+[^/]+/([^/]+/)+[^#]+(#.+)?$', 'http://www.example.es/cat1/cat2/some-example_DH148439#.Rh1-js_4') != None
True
>>> re.match(r'^[^:]+://([^.]+\.)+[^/]+/([^/]+/)+[^#]+(#.+)?$', 'http://www.example.es/cat1/cat2/cat3') != None
True
```

but the regex I'm giving is good enough to answer your question, but is not a good way to validate an URL, or to split it in pieces. I'd say its only interest is to actually answer your question.

Here's the automaton generated by the regex, to better understand it:

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Beware of what you're asking, because JL's regex won't match:

```
http://www.example.es/cat1/cat2/cat3
```

as after rereading your question 3×, you're actually asking for the following regex:

```
\/([^/]*)$
```

which will match both your examples:

```
http://www.example.es/cat1/cat2/some-example_DH148439#.Rh1-js_4
http://www.example.es/cat1/cat2/cat3
```

What @jl-peyret suggests, is only how to *match a litteral dot following a `/`*, which is generating the following automaton:

[image: Regular expression visualization]

So, whatever you really want:

1. use urlparse whenever you can to match parts of an URL
2. if you're trying to define a django route, then trying to match the fragment is hopeless
3. next time you do a question, please make it precise, and give an example of what you tried: help us help you.

Comment: Why wouldn't that work in django? Besides the fact that the fragment part is only being used on the client side, the OP's question is pretty clear: he wants to match URLs. I'm not trying to guess what the OP is trying to do, and @w3d already made a comment about the fact that the fragment part is going to be eaten.

Comment: I mean that in django routing you *need* to use a regex.  Otherwise a split on / followed by a . check would do.

Comment: indeed, though it's not what the OP is asking, whatever he's actually asking…

Comment: Well, I don't disagree with the old joke that sometimes a programmer starting out with one problem to solve and using a regex on it now has 2 problems...  BTW, I did test that my regex did **not** match his cat2/cat3, but I really couldn't figure out from the question how you could ask for a regex that both needed a '.' and also didn't care if there was a '.' so I assumed he forgot to mention cat2/cat3 was **not** supposed to match.  Question:  where did you get your state diagram from?  I often can use help on regexes.

Comment: Some guy wrote http://debuggex.com which is great, have a try, you can run your regex through the diagram it's quite fun. Though, it is *NOT* a state diagram, it is an *automaton*, more precisely an NFA. To read more about that, I have an old answer about regex where I gave [a few useful resources](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23654544/1290438) you might want to read. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

```
\/([^\/]*\.+[^\/]*)$
```

The first / forces you to look after it.  The $ forces end of string and 
both class negations avoid any / between.
check @ https://regex101.com/

Answer (score 1):

I would use a look-ahead like so

```
(?=.*\.)([^/]+$)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/yW4aZ3/272)

```
(?=             # Look-Ahead
  .             # Any character except line break
  *             # (zero or more)(greedy)
  \.            # "."
)               # End of Look-Ahead
(               # Capturing Group (1)
  [^/]          # Character not in [/] Character Class
  +             # (one or more)(greedy)
  $             # End of string/line
)               # End of Capturing Group (1)
```

or a negative look-ahead like so

```
(?!.*\.)([^/]+$)
```

for the opposite case