# Escaping close-bracket character in grep complement

Tags: regex, grep

How do I escape a close-bracket character inside a character class? According to the manual, to match a literal ] it should be placed first in the list, but I need to match the complement of a class consisting of square bracket.

> Most  meta-characters  lose  their  special  meaning inside bracket expressions.  To include a literal ] place it first in the list. Similarly, to include a literal ^ place it anywhere but first.  Finally, to include a literal - place it last.

Comment: you mean this `[\]]`?

Comment: An example would be better.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### How do I escape a close-bracket character inside a character class?

A `]` is normally either the end of a [POSIX character class](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrecharclass.html#POSIX-Character-Classes), or it signals the end of the character class.

If a `]` is the first character in the class (***may follow an unescaped caret***) it does not denote the end of the class and is evaluated as part of the set of characters that can be matched without escaping.

```
echo "foo [22-Jun-2014 04:11:37 UTC] bar" | grep -o '\[[^]]*\]'
# [22-Jun-2014 04:11:37 UTC]
```

Answer (score 4):

It depends on the implementation.

- In `grep -P` mode, you can actually use `[][]` to match a char that is either an opening or closing bracket.
- In general the syntax that is the most portable is to escape: `[\]]` and `[\[]`

**Related**

[What does the “[^][]” regex mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17845014/what-does-the-regex-mean/17845034#17845034)

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, zx81's solution did not work. In particular, for the input:

> [22-Jun-2014 04:11:37 UTC]

```
grep -o '.[^[\]]*'
```

fails.

What did work was not escaping the closing bracket at all:

```
grep '^[[][^]]*]'
```

It seems that grep still considers the closing bracket as first even if it is preceded by a caret.

Comment: It should be `grep -o '.[^][]*' `, i.e. putting `]` first.

Answer (score 0):

```
user$ sleep 400 &
[1] 13242
user$ sleep 500 &
[2] 13253
user$ jobs
[1]-  Running                 sleep 400 &
[2]+  Running                 sleep 500 &
user$ jobs | grep "sleep 400" | grep -o ^"["[0-9][0-9]*"]"
[1]
user$ jobs | grep "sleep 500" | grep -o ^"["[0-9][0-9]*"]"
[2]
```

Why does this work?

The square brackets are treated as strings and without any explicit escape character, they are not the part of the `grep` regular expression special literals.