# How to modify this REGEX to allow nested Bracket

Tags: regex

My regex allow for now spin syntax {spin1|spin2}

```
  $customContent = preg_replace('/(\{)(.*?)(})/', '{#'.$index.'#}', $customContent, 1);
```

I would like to allow unlimited nested bracket { {spin1|spin2} {blabla1|blabla2} }

Could you help me to fix this regex please ?

I have tried the below solutions. None worked.

```
/{([^{}]*)}/

/(?<={)[^}]*(?=})/

/(\{(?:\{.*\}|[^\{])*\})/m

/\{(((?>[^\{\}]+)|(?R))*)\}/x

/\{.*?\}/i
```

Comment: Check out [Bart's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14952740), [Casimir et Hippolyte's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17845034) is also outstanding...

Comment: Hamza thx you but im not expert event i understand a little bit, im gonna read it but not sure i will done it

Comment: Recursive patterns are one of the advanced techniques in regex. If you're still a beginner, you might need to practice and read more about regex and common patterns in general. If you're already a bit familiar with regex, you might read [this article](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-recursion.html).

Comment: @user3216977 still i don't understand your question. Check this out http://regex101.com/r/bR2iB6/4

Answer (score -1):

Unlimited nesting bracket, with unlimited depth, not empty content: (JS syntax)

```
/(\s*\{[^\{\}]+\}\s*)+/g
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/nhpUzo/1)

-- EDIT --

Is this what you meant?

```
/[^{}]*{\s*([^{}]+)?}?\s*[^{}]*/g
```

[DEMO](http://regex101.com/r/sO9pY0/5)

Comment: Thx you but both code dont work on my spinner :) i tried also          /(\s*\{[^\{\}]+\}\s*)+/

Comment: Try this syntax, it works on regex tester http://regex101.com/r/sO9pY0/2

Comment: Unlimited depth not working: http://regex101.com/r/sO9pY0/3

Comment: This way unlimited depth working http://regex101.com/r/sO9pY0/4

Comment: Refined version, skip empty strings made of whitespaces http://regex101.com/r/sO9pY0/5