# How to get all in the most outer brackets?

Tags: regex

I have a string like `aaaaaa(bbbbb(ccccccc)dddddd)eeeeeefffff)hhhhh(iiiiii`, how to write a Regular Expression which could get `bbbbb(ccccccc)dddddd`.

In example above, there are two pair of brackets, one pair is in another one.  i want get all content in the outer.

I have no idea about it.

Comment: your example seems unclear for me.. Single example wouldn't be enough give more..

Comment: Regex is horrible at nesting. Use a tokenizer/parser instead.

Comment: @h2ooooooo `Regex is horrible at nesting`. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: All answers below are horrible. See [the duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14952740/), [a perl/pcre solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17845034) and [a .net solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17004406)

Comment: @HamZa yes it's horrible but he fail to explain his question clearly.

Comment: @AvinashRaj How come I've found 3 duplicates in no time?

Comment: i posted an answer after seeing the accepted answer. I already posted a comment to explain the question clearly http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26251119/how-to-get-all-in-the-most-outer-brackets/26251528#comment41179462_26251119.

Comment: A different approach: http://pastebin.com/YHgn6A76

Comment: @AvinashRaj At first thanks for everybody here answers this question though it is not clearly described. I've searched  before I posted my question, because of wrong key words i used, I didn't find useful thing. Maybe It will take days for me to see every link and understand them. It's a wonderful place here indeed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May not be the best solution, but this might work for your case:

```
var regex = /\((.*?\(.*?\).*?)\)/;
```

Here's a snippet to test things out:

```js
    var string = 'aaaaaa(bbbbb(ccccccc)dddddd)eeeeeefffff)hhhhh(iiiiii',
      matches = string.match(/\((.*?\(.*?\).*?)\)/);

    console.log(matches[1]);
```

Comment: Your solution is perfect for my problem.